# How to filter a column in a data frame by the regex value of another column in same data frame in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter a column in data frame that matches the regex pattern given in another column

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('what is the movie that features Tom Cruise','actor_movies','(movie|film).*(feature)|(in|on).*(movie|film)'),
    ('what is the movie that features Tom Cruise','artist_song','(who|what).*(sing|sang|perform)'),
    ('who is the singer for hotel califonia?','artist_song','(who|what).*(sing|sang|perform)')],  
['query','question_type','regex_patt'])

+--------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------- -+
|               query                   |question_type  |regex_patt|
+--------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
|what movie features Tom Cruise         | actor_movies  | (movie|film).*(feature)|(in|on).*(movie|film)
|what movie features Tom Cruise         | artist_song   | (who|what).*(sing|sang|perform)
|who is the singer for hotel califonia  | artist_song   | (who|what).*(sing|sang|perform) |
 +--------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to prune the data frame such that only to keep rows whose query matches the regex_pattern column value.
The final result should like this

```
+--------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------- -+
|               query                   |question_type  |regex_patt|
+--------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
|what movie features Tom Cruise         | actor_movies  | (movie|film).*(feature)|(in|on).*(movie|film)|
|who is the singer for hotel califonia  | artist_song   | (who|what).*(sing|sang|perform) 
 +--------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I was thinking of

```
df.filter(column('query').rlike('regex_patt'))
```

But rlike only accepts regex strings.

Now the question is,   how to filter the `"query"` column based on the regex value of `"regex_patt"` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this. The expression allows you to put columns as the str and pattern.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("query1", F.expr("""regexp_extract(query, regex_patt)""")).filter(F.col("query1")!='').drop("query1").show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+
|query                                     |question_type|regex_patt                                   |
+------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+
|what is the movie that features Tom Cruise|actor_movies |(movie|film).*(feature)|(in|on).*(movie|film)|
|who is the singer for hotel califonia?    |artist_song  |(who|what).*(sing|sang|perform)              |
+------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks a lot , how can put a alias name inside expr() ? any sample plz